Would TCP cubic congestion control always cause packet loss as it tries to increase window size until packet drop?
Setup:
Sender talking to receiver through a ToR where all interfaces are 100 Gbps but the ToR has a smart flow limiter that drops packets if the throughput for a flow is above 10 Gbps.
Traffic:
Sender CPU is capable of making enough syscalls and the NIC together is capable of sustaining > 10 Gbps traffic (say 25 Gbps, assuming TCP segments are jumbo size).  Let's assume the receiver is copying out the kernel buffer quickly enough to sustaining this throughput.
Congestion control:
Say we are using Cubic
Question:
The sender would do slow start, and then try to additively increase cwnd until the ToR flow limiter drops a packet.  This would cause cwnd to half.  Would this cycle would repeat as long as the traffic is running.  Wouldn't this cause an enormous number of packet drops?

If the local link permits, any TCP congestion control temporarily exceeds the current path bandwidth and loses packets. That's the only way to detect the available bandwidth.
